# Unity ARKit - plane detection doesn't work well?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, plane

Ok, just doing the basic horizontal plane detection and granted, haven't updated to Unity ARKit 1.5 with vertical but Im thinking it shouldn't matter - why is Unity's plane detection, not having touched anything, so bad?

I deploy to my iPhone and the blue planes overlap and don't detect some obvious surfaces, like my laptop for example. I have decent lighting - what can I do to fix this?

(not getting laptop)
[image]

Comment: Provide an MCVE with screenshots of current results and a more detailed explanation of expected results? Surely you should know this by now with 2K+ rep...

Comment: I thought this was a common problem - in question is picture, loading now. What is an MCVE?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. And code?